# I don't know how to add an id to make relation between my post and my comment (React JS/Strapi)

Tags: reactjs, relational-database, strapi

I use React JS and Strapi. I am trying to send comment to my API. I worked but without one essential thing : the post for which I am writing a comment. How can I possibly add the id of my post so that the relation is made between my comment and my post ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import CommentsAPI from '../../Services/CommentsAPI'

export default function CommentForm() {

    const [comment, setComment] = useState({})
    const {id} = useParams()

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}`))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.currentTarget
        setComment({
            ...comment,
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <TextField 
                    id="pseudo" 
                    label="Pseudo" 
                    type="text" 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="pseudo"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <TextField
                    id="comment"
                    label="Comment"
                    multiline
                    minRows={2}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="content"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Send
                </Button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```
import { URL_COMMENTS } from '../config'
import axios from 'axios'

function create(id_post, comment) {
    return axios.post(URL_COMMENTS, id_post, comment)
}

const CommentsAPI = {
    create
}

export default CommentsAPI
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Extend your CommentsAPI to take a post ID along with the comment. Is that id from useParams an id of the post? If not you would need to pass it from the parent. Also, you might have to update your back-end to handle post id

Comment: I have tried it : CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":{"id":${id}, "attributes":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}}`)) and it didn't work. At the moment, I don't see an other solution. Thank you for your answer. Yes, useParam in the id of the post. However, I agree to try "parenthood" at some point.

Comment: So I extended my CommentsAPI (it's added on the description). I know there is something missing... Do you know how I can include the post id ?